# SVG text error - text getting collapsed and doesn't show properly

Tags: svg

In the example http://jsfiddle.net/q5yN3/1/ could anyone tell me why does the Text Example gets collapsed and doesn't show properly? Am I missing some property of the  tag or should I add it differently?

```
    <text font-family="Tahoma" font-size="8" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(533316.59375 -4757133.5)">Text Example</text>
```

I'm using Firefox.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "collapse"?

Answer (score 0):

The text element is inside a `<g>` element that has an extreme zoom-out scale factor applied to it:

```
<g transform="translate(0 85) scale(1)">
    <g transform="translate(221 2952) scale(0.000607469)">
        <text font-family="Tahoma" font-size="8" text-anchor="middle" 
        transform="translate(533316.59375 -4757133.5)"
        >Text Example</text>
```

That scale factor applies to the font-size as well, so your text is being drawn as 8px*0.000607469 = a tiny fraction of a pixel tall.  The only reason the text is visible in other browsers is because of accessibility features which prevent them from drawing super-tiny text.

The solution is simply to reverse the scale factor from the `<g>` element on the `<text>` element:

```
<g transform="translate(0 85) scale(1)">
    <g transform="translate(221 2952) scale(0.000607469)">
        <text font-family="Tahoma" font-size="8" text-anchor="middle" 
        transform="translate(533316.59375 -4757133.5) scale(1646)"
        >Text Example</text>
```

Note that the reverse scale is added *after* the translation, so the units for the translation are still in the scaled coordinates.